# Can I burn an NFT via smart contract using the Wallet address when an owner gives permission?

Tags: blockchain, nft, opensea

If I have a game whereby there are a number of NFT game pieces that have lost the game, can I burn them via the Smart contract?

For clarity; the NFT's are minted and in the wallets of the players. The players have a choice of continuing to play the game, however if their game piece dies, the NFT gets burned.

Options that I can see at the moment are;
Player burns them themselves, reports that back and it gets checked via the ledger.
Player 'Gifts' the NFT back as part of their choice to continue playing, then upon death, I burn the NFT.

Any suggestion on how to automate this within the smart contract as I don't want to rely on the player click the 'Burn' button on Opensea or have to go through each gifted NFT and burn manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. What blockchain are you using? Needs to support kind of automation and the transfer function (to burn the token) needs to be called from either the owner of the token contract OR via a contract call to avoid fees. Then the contract call needs to be triggered via an external event.

Comment: Hi Yiannis, thanks for taking the time to answer, I appreciate it. Based on Ethereum, using Chainlink for randomness within the game, there are a number of rounds during which the player can choose a path, however that path my lead to your NFT Characters death at which point it needs to be burned. As I understand it, the act of Burning is a standard transaction and will incur a fee (approx. $2 -$3).

Comment: I would like the burn event called via the admin dashboard upon completion of each round. Possible?

Comment: Thanks for the details. If I have the structure of your game correct, you have few options depending on the frequency you want the burn to happen. 

You can use external services like Chainlink keepers or Gelato

[link](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/#custom-logic-trigger)
[link](https://www.gelato.network)

Maybe also a simple callback function if it's synchronous? 

function customGameLogic(address callbackAddress) public {
       // Your logic here
        require(callbackAddress.call(bytes4(keccak256("burn(tokenId)"))));
    }

Just some ideas

Comment: Hi Yiannis, apologies for the delayed reply and thank you for the update. Unfortunately I have run into a couple of other issues that need addressing before I can move on; 1st is, I've added a metadata variable but Opensea won't display it! And I'm having issues minting through iOS (Desktop and Android are fine), keeps coming back with an 'error in the Smart Contract ', so frustrating.